# Reopen "Will relocating close off future opportunities elsewhere?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

The question [Will relocating close off future opportunities elsewhere?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/123513/will-relocating-close-off-future-opportunities-elsewhere) was put on hold for "asking for advice on a specific choice." While the OP is trying to decide between two jobs, the question is *not* asking which job to take. The question is asking about a specific aspect of the decision, specifically whether moving to one location would close off opportunities in the other.

I believe this question is on-topic and should be reopened.

Comment: 3rd vote has been cast

Comment: I agree that the question was and is on-topic. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe this question is on-topic and should be reopened.

Casted the fifth and final vote; now the question is open again.